# Using variables declared in a loop or declaring them outside the loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am a beginner at java and programing in general and I've stumbeled across a problem.

```
int[][]table = new int[numberOfShortTables][legnthOfShortTable]   

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShortTables; i++) {
    char[]shortTable = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
    for(int k = 0;k<legnthOfShortTable;k++){
        table[i][k]=shortTable[k];
    } 
}
```

Later in the code I need to use both `table[][]` and `shortTable[]`.

My question is:
Is it possible to declare a variable inside a loop in a way, that it will be usable outside it?

In case that's not possible, I'm wondering how to declare the `shortTable[]` outside the loop and use the `sc.nextLine().toCharArray();` inside it.

Comment: What is *sc* then?

Comment: `char[] shortTable;  for(int i=0;i<numberOfShortTables; i++){ shortTable = sc.nextLine().toCharArray(); ...} `

Comment: Outside of the loop: `char[] shortTable;`  Inside of the loop: `shortTable = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();`

Comment: Note that `table[][]` contains all the data from `shortTable[]`, e.g `table[0]` has exactly the same content as `shortTable[]`, so maybe you don't need the latter after the loop .

Comment: if you cant ensure the length of *shortTable* is always bigger than *legnthOfShortTable* your program will throw * java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException*

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the variable is inside the code block where it was declared, so No, you cannot declare a variable inside a loop and then use is outside.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, all you need to do is declare the var outside the loop first with `char[]shortTable;` or something similar, then assign to it inside the loop with `shortTable = ...`.  This is just normal variable scoping, there's nothing special about the loop.

You can do the same thing with the loop variable itself.  `int i;` a few lines up, then `for (i = 0....`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi so it looks like you need to go read up on scope a bit..

To answer your question the way that you have it now you wont be able to use char[]shortTable later on after the for loop so just hoist it above the for loop and you will be able to use it. If you need to use it in other methods aswell please see below for a bit more info. (NB avoid static where possible as a beginner it will give you endless headaches if you don't understand the implications 100%)

In short you get 3 types of scope for Classes

- private : This means that you can access that variable or method from only within that class
- public : This means that the variable or method will be accessible outside the class from anything that has access to the instantiated object.
- protected : This means that anything that extends the class would be able to have access to that variable or method.

When you define variables in at a class level they will be available to all methods in that class.

When you define a variable in a method it will be accessible to all loops/conditional checks within that method i.e. inside for, while and if statements.

When you define a variable inside a for, while and if statement the variable will only be accessible inside that loop (Think of it as a method inside a method and the variable is only available to the method that defined it.)

Hope that helps a bit to understand scope a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Is it possible to declare a variable inside a loop in a way, that it will be usable outside it?

No, not possible.

> In case that's not possible, I'm wondering how to declare the shortTable[] outside the loop and use the sc.nextLine().toCharArray(); inside it.

You don't have to declare shortTable[] inside the loop if you plan to use it outside your loop. Just declare it outside the loop. Doing so allows you to use it in the loop as well.